# C# Get var name to string

Tags: c#

greetings, could you please help? i need to get a variable (name) in string format. for example below i need to display "test" as string.

```
        int test = 69;
        //below does not work
        MessageBox.Show((string)test);
        // below works but displays the int value
        MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
```

thank you for your time.

well i have an enum:

```
    public enum ShipOrientation
    {
        North,
        East,
        South,
        West
    }
```

and i do some processing based on direction and if int North then apply enum North direction.

Comment: "then apply enum direction" - what do you mean?  Can you give a full sample that includes the variables that you wish to string-ize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not for variables, but if you promote your variable to a property on the class, you can use Expressions to achieve this.

good sample [here](http://beta.blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/smallfish/archive/2009/04/02/how-to-get-a-property-name-using-lambda-expression-in-c-3-0.aspx)

Comment: And also you may use Reflection to retrieve member names.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.aspx

Comment: generally the reflection approach would need a string as input to find the property

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done normally - variable names are compiled out in C#.

On the other hand, if you can *write* the variable's name, you  can just place quotation marks around it and treat it as a string.

Assuming that's not good enough for your scenario, there are a few hacks that can let you do something *almost* like this; but their usefulness kind of depends on what you're trying to do - why do you need to variable's name?

Comment: Actually, this *can* be done, but the code is *very* hackish:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing.aspx

Comment: Yes, I realize: that's one of the hacks I'm referring to.  At that point, you're no longer working with variables, but on type members - which can be reflected upon.